# How can I load different components in the same page

Tags: vue.js

Each user type in my app needs to have a different dashboard, so, at the moment, my admin vue looks like the following:

```
<template>
    <main id="admin-main">
        <header id="admin-dashboard-header" class="jumbotron">
            <div>
                <h1>Job Dashboard</h1>
                <p>Worker > Dashboard</p>
            </div>
        </header>

        <div class="row container">
            <div class="col-4">
                <ul class="list-group text-center">
                    <li class="list-group-item active">Dashboard</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Companies</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Jobs</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Candidates</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-8">
                All components must load here
            </div>
        </div>


    </main>
</template>

<style scoped>
h1{
    font-size: 50px;
}
</style>
```

Ideally, each list item(Companies, Jobs, Candidates) must load their respective component.
So, for instance, how can I load jobs component in this same page when I click on the jobs list item?

Comment: you mean you want to load more than one component on the page at the same time ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution would be to use dynamic components. See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components

You can see an example I made here: https://codepen.io/bergur/pen/bPEJdB

In my Vue app I've made a data property called `selectedComponent`, and defined a method that sets that property according to the parameter

```
setComponent(name) {
  this.selectedComponent = name
}
```

You then invoke that function with something like:

```
<button @click="setComponent('menuList')">Menu List</button>
```

And here is the real magic

```
<component :is="selectedComponent" />
```

So when I press the button. The data property selectedComponent gets the value menuList which is the registered component.

The component tag then renders that component.

Comment: Yes. Dynamic Components. I didnt know the name and it became more difficult to find out the answer initially. I followed the documentation and they actually provide a fiddle with a snippet that you might want to take a look.
https://jsfiddle.net/chrisvfritz/o3nycadu/
Appreciate the support